# Moving application to the clould - how to design bi directional sync between clients - table design

Tags: mobile, synchronization, azure-sql-database, tablet, windows-8

I currently have a WPF consumer application and my users want to view and update information on mobile devices and tablets. I am planning to support ipad, iphone and windows8 metro.

I want to build a new application with cloud syncing abilities. I am planning to use the Azure platform to store a database and host services.

Given that a user may have multiple devices which may be connected or disconntected and they perform edits, deletes etc, what changes should I make to my tables to handle bi-directional syncing of data?

If the user has 2 devices, deletes a record on device and then on a second device edits the record instead and then syncs both devices to the cloud, is the record deleted or updated? How do you keep track of these changes? Would adding the columns: created and last updated be sufficient to track these changes?

What is the best approach in syncing data in hybrid applications?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the [Sync Framework Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e)

this is a toolkit built on top of Sync Framework with OData and if am not mistaken it has samples for iPhone and HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the open source project, OpenMobster's Sync service. You can do the following sync operations

- two-way
- one-way client
- one-way device
- bootup

Besides that, all modifications are automatically tracked and synced with the Cloud. You can have your app offline when network connection is down. It will track any changes and automatically in the background synchronize it with the cloud when the connection returns.

It also supports sync across multiple devices like iCloud does.

As per your question, is it deleted or is it updated, in my engine it would be deleted with the reasoning being someone wants the record deleted regardless of its state. I understand the other argument holds true as well. But with sync engines and conflict resolution you have to go with some behavior and stay consistent

Currently only native development is supported on Android and iOS. However, the next release which is 2.2-M8 will support end-to-end integration with PhoneGap on Android and 2.2-M9 will add iOS.

Here is a link to the open source project: http://openmobster.googlecode.com

Here is a tutorial to understand some of its workings: http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/AndroidSyncApp